# Is the function $(xy)^{1/3}$ differentiable at (0,0)?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Is the function $(xy)^{1/3}$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

**My trial:**

No, as I calculated $r(x,y)$ and it turned out to be $(xy)^{1/3}$, then I calculated the limit $\frac {(xy)^{2/3}}{x^2 + y^2}$ at (0,0) and it turned out that it does not exist hence the function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ . Am I correct?

Comment: I will attach the formula I am using.

Comment: Where did that second function come from?

Comment: @Arthur I have edited my question

Comment: @Displayname   I have edited my question

Comment: yes they are @dmtri

Comment: @Artur,   you are right,  my misunderstanding,  sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function is differentiable, then all its directional derivatives must exist (and they must also play along with one another in a particularily nice way, which is what that formula of yours is putting in rigorous terms).

Let's look at the line $x = y$. Does your function have a directional derivative along this line?

The (or rather, *a*) directional derivative along that line is given by
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t, t) - f(0,0)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^{2/3} - 0}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\left(t^{-1/3}\right)
$$
which doesn't exist.

Therefore your function doesn't have directional derivatives in all directions, which means it cannot be differentiable.

Comment: but the theorem mentioned in the other answer is written in my book ..... may be I am mistaking the direction of the implication?

Comment: @Happy Take a look at that theorem. What is $r(t, t)$? Does that look like something in my answer? I've basically done the same thing here as that theorem of yours does, only used different words to explain why it's right.

Comment: also the function $xy/\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$ if $x^2 + y^2 \neq 1$ and 0 otherwise turned out to be not differentiable at (0,0) by the same method , am I correct?

Comment: @Happy I think you mean "if $x^2 + y^2\neq 0$". But that function _is_ differentiable at $(0,0)$. Note that, say, along the line $x = y$, the same directional derivative as above becomes $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t^2}{|t|}$, which certainly exists.

Comment: yes you are correct .... you mean it is differentiable/

Comment: the limit depends on the path ..... I took the path $y = mx$

Comment: @Happy Yes, sorry. I got confused between continuous and differentiable. Yes, that function is continuous but not differentiable at $(0,0)$.